# SQLAlchemy commit error after 17 minutes

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a weird problem with mysql and sqlalchemy.
Everything work fine 99% of the time but some time my code take 17 minutes to execute and throw this exception:

> Exception raised on 'commit' : (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL
>   server during query')

Here is the code:

```
self.engine = create_engine(uri, echo=False, poolclass=NullPool)
session_maker = orm.sessionmaker(
    bind=self.engine,
    expire_on_commit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    extension=None
)
self.session = self.orm.scoping.scoped_session(session_maker)
self.session.add(entity) # it's a simple object I want to insert
self.session.commit()
```

I activate in mysql:

- slow query log
- print deadlock in innodb

Nothing in these logs for my error.
The idle connection in mysql is 30 minutes
The idle connection in mysql front load balancer is 4 minutes

So I have no more idea for my bug.

Have you a new idea ?

Comment: since you are using NullPool,it seems not like the MySQL connection go away problem. would you mind sharing the exception stack wtih us?

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout with connect_args

```
self.engine = create_engine(uri, echo=False, poolclass=NullPool ,connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10})
```

[Check here for more info](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/connections.html#how-do-i-pass-custom-connect-arguments-to-my-database-api) !!!

Comment: I saw this point indeed but I don't see the link with mysql lost connection. Can you explain me please ?

Comment: I thought that it might be timeout issue since currently no other obvious reason is there. You can configure connect_timeout to more than 20 minutes and test it

Comment: The default connect_timeout seems to be 10 seconds https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/dc01c6e7cd06cf523d67140b26afea365c130192/pymysql/connections.py#L584 so I don't think it's the good path.